# what appx ( x86/ARM ) to upload on windows phone store with SQLite

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am having a confusion uploading my Windows Phone 8.1 app.

What type of appx(x86/ARM) I need to upload on Windows Phone store to make my app work on all devices ? 

Note that I am using SQLite in my project so I can't select AnyCPU.

**EDIT:**

I have tried uploading more than 1 package on store like 1 appx for ARM and another appx for x86 but store does not allow to have more than 1 package.

Comment: Windows Phone only supports ARM packages.  There should be no reason to use x86 at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Phone only supports ARM packages, x86 is for emulator.
So, only ARM package is needed to upload on Windows Phone store.